# error 500 strict-origin-when-cross-origin in go daddy hosting

Tags: php, api, apache, http-headers, godaddy-api

Getting cross origin error in network console when I'm loading this page, please help
added .htaccess file and add header code also in my php file. I purchased the Go Daddy hosting.
I have attached the network screenshot

[image: Screenshot of network console]

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');



$conn= mysql_connect("localhost","***********","*********");

if (!$conn) {
    echo "Unable to connect to DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (!mysql_select_db("canvasinfra")) {
    echo "Unable to select mydbname: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

$sql = "SELECT id,blocks FROM canvas_blockmaster where ProjectId='1' order by blocks asc";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
    echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
    exit;
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["id"];
    echo $row["blocks"];
}

mysql_free_result($result);

?>
```

Comment: What's your web server, Apahce or Nginx? Have you ever checked the server log or PHP error_log?

Comment: apache, go daddy linux hosting